# Data class without default constructor

Tags: kotlin, constructor, data-class

I have these fields in my data class:

```
    val year: Int,
    val month: Int? = null,
    val day: Int? = null,
```

How can I insure via constructor that If `day` in not-null, `month` is not null as well?
Ideally, I wanna have only 3 constructors without default nullable fields at all.

```
(year: Int) (year: Int, month: Int) and (year: Int, month: Int, day: Int)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a normal class, with a private constructor, and add your overloaded constructors:

```
class X private constructor(val year: Int, val month: Int?, val day: Int?) {
    constructor(year: Int) : this(year, null, null)
    constructor(year: Int, month: Int) : this(year, month, null)
    constructor(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) : this(year, month, day as Int?)

    // Optionally create equals, hashCode, toString and componentN methods...
}
```

If you need any of the extra methods that a `data class` would have auto-generated, just add them manually, or let your IDE generate them for you.

**Rationale**

Why did we create a normal class? Well, you *could* create a data class with a private constructor, but that wouldn't prevent the user of your class from calling the `copy` function and passing invalid parameters to it, such as a day with a null month.

Unlike `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals`, you cannot override the `copy` function or disable it in any way. If you declare your class as a data class, you'll get an unwanted `copy` function that you can't get rid of. With a normal class, you can define your own logic in the `copy` function, though you probably wouldn't want to define it at all as it's problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some sort of factory that would enforce types and perhaps other validation (negative values, etc...). One way of doing this is by using a companion object.

As @gidds commented, while the constructor can be private, "invalid" instances can still be created by using [copy()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying)

```
data class MyDate 
private constructor(val year: Int, val month: Int? = null, val day: Int? = null) {
    companion object {
        fun from(year: Int) = MyDate(year, null, null)
        fun from(year: Int, month: Int) = MyDate(year, month, null)
        fun from(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) = MyDate(year, month, day)
    }
}

fun main() {
    MyDate.from(2023)
        .also { println(it) } // MyDate(year=2023, month=null, day=null)
    MyDate.from(2023, 11)
        .also { println(it) } // MyDate(year=2023, month=11, day=null)
    MyDate.from(2023, 11, 9)
        .also { println(it) } // MyDate(year=2023, month=11, day=9)
    // Invalid instances can still be created using copy()
    MyDate.from(2023, 11, 9).copy(month = null)
        .also { println(it) } // MyDate(year=2023, month=null, day=9)
}
```

There are options to create various date object out-of-the-box, I assume that they are not a good fit for what you have in mind.

Comment: Good point, amended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface that resembles a data class in its usage:

```
sealed interface FlexibleDate {
    val year: Int
    val month: Int?
    val day: Int?

    operator fun component1() = year
    operator fun component2() = month
    operator fun component3() = day
    
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(year: Int): FlexibleDate = Impl(year, null, null)
        operator fun invoke(year: Int, month: Int): FlexibleDate = Impl(year, month, null)
        operator fun invoke(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int): FlexibleDate = Impl(year, month, day)
    }

     private data class Impl(override val year: Int, override val month: Int?, override val day: Int?) : FlexibleDate
}
```

The private implementation class `Impl` provides the correctly generated implementations of `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` that all data classes have.

The interface provides `invoke` functions so that you can create instances as though it had constructors. The overloads of `invoke` won't accept a day without a month.

Comment: Nice one, why `sealed` ?

Comment: @DavidSoroko It doesn't have to be sealed, but I wanted to make it as close as possible to a data class. A data class cannot be extended. Likewise, a sealed interface cannot be implemented (that is, once you've put your library in its own module).